# Detecting and clearing a form field in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I ran into a problem the other day when building a form.
The input box has a type "number".
In Chrome the input field displays up/down arrows. I could not detect change when either the up or down buttons were clicked, so I used CSS to remove the buttons. That was pretty simple, but it did not resolve all of my problems.

I do some validation on the field (using keyup). If I enter a number in the field it works fine, but if I enter a letter into the field I cannot detect it.

Using .val() works fine in FF and IE to get the field's value (number or letter), but in Chrome, not so much.
If there is a letter in the field I cannot find a way to clear the field either. Using .val('') simply moves the cursor to the left.

As I said, this problem is specific to using Chrome. For all other browsers my code works fine.

Any suggestions on code that can be used to resolve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We can be a lot more help if you post the code you're having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

The issue all revolves around the input being of type "number".

The HTML5 draft defines:

The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the element is not a valid floating point number, then set it to the empty string instead.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state

Trying to do a .val() to retrieve a type=number input that has a non-number in it will only return the empty string.  It looks like Chrome's implementation of this is to set the value of the field to empty string before any value can actually be retrieved.

As far as resetting the field using .val('') and keyup not being recognized, this code seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/hVVSA/2/

JS

```
var $input = $('input').keyup(function(){
  console.log("here");
});

$('#clearfield').click(function(){
  console.log('val was '+$input.val());
  $input.val('');
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="number" />

<button id="clearfield">clear</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Clearing the field in the way you describe definitely seems to work. Is there no way of getting the value if it's not a number? Without being able to do this it is not going to be easy to do validation.

Comment: In your validation can't you just check if it's an empty string and if it is you can either assume A) it WAS a non-number or B) they never entered anything into it?  In either case, you should be able to take the appropriate action.  Otherwise, you could always just use a normal input field and do validation to ensure it's a number using either `isNaN()` or `/^\d+$/.test(input)`.

Comment: Yeah, I already thought about doing that. There must be something screwy in my code as $('#id').val(''); is not clearing the field. Using the code snippet you provided, it does, which is a bit confusing for me. A bit more D&C required, me thinks...

Comment: Okay... here is what I have found. Using a button to clear the field works fine, but if you try and clear the field using $('#id').val(''); in the keyup function it does not. Any idea of how I can get around that problem???

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure why that occurs.

Comment: Therein lies my problem. I am open to suggestions from anyone that might have a solution to this Chrome specific issue. BTW, thanks for your responses joeltine. They led me to discovering exactly where it's going pear shaped.